# Normal and naive Bayes - duplicating data, improves classification [Weka]

Tags: machine-learning, weka, bayesian-networks

I wanted to examine how bayes network will behave if I only will manipulate size of data set.

Since I still think about data generator (cant find proper article) I have decided to just multiple the data I have. I thought if I will only duplicate it, it won't change the classification results - just model creation time.

Well I did the tests on 2 data-sets:

data1: 70 instances, 8 attributes, yes/no classification

data2: 768 instances, 206 attributes, 1-6 type classification

The results on computing time on original sets are between 0-0.01 sec, so I can't get much from it. The interesting numbers comes after I multiplied the data.

The testing method was cross-validation on 10 folds.
Everything done in Weka.

.

Format:

Number_of_instances : model_creation_time : %Correctly_Clasified_instances

---

Data1, Naive Bayes:

768  :  0s : 76.3021%

7680 : 0.01s : 76.2891%

76800 : 0.11s : 76.2708%

768000 : 1.39s : 76.3021%

---

Data1, Normal Bayes:

768 : 0.02s : 74.349%

7680 : 0.08s : 85.7943%

76800 : 1.43s : 97.8659%

768000: 26.18s : 97.824%

---

Data2, Naive Bayes:

70 : 0s : 82.8571%

700 : 0s : 92%

7000: 0.02s : 94.2857%

70000 : 0.21sec : 94.2857%

---

Data2, Normal bayes:

70 : 0.01s : 82.8571%

700 : 0.01s : 93.2857%

7000 : 0.11s : 94.2857%

70000 : 2.63s : 94.2857%

---

The computing time in all cases increased (Normal bayes took more time - but in data2 with more attributes it grows much slower).

The properly classified instances highly raised only in normal bayes in data1 (8 attributes).

While on data2 (206 attributes) classification improved greatly on both methods.

How the duplication of data helped in classification? Did I do something wrong or those are some kind of fake results? Can it be explained?

Answer (score 1):

of course accuracy increses if samples are douplicated. think about it. you have more of the same data, so clasifier trains harder on it

if you want test diferent sample count, you should remove samples, not add them

hope I was help

good day

Comment: Thanks.
What about Naive&Normal bayes efficenty increase in data2 while Naive in data1 stagnation?